# ERROR: FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable join conditions

Tags: mysql

when i try to join tables with inner join..it returns the data..but when i join 4 tables with full outer join then i says

> ERROR:  FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable join conditions"

An example query:

```
SELECT hr_employee.name,hr_movement.amount,hr_concept.name,hr_period.name
FROM hr_employee
FULL OUTER JOIN hr_movement
ON hr_employee.ad_client_id=hr_movement.ad_client_id
FULL OUTER JOIN hr_concept
ON hr_movement.ad_client_id=hr_employee.ad_client_id
FULL OUTER JOIN hr_period
ON hr_concept.ad_client_id=hr_employee.ad_client_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT hr_employee.name,hr_movement.amount,hr_concept.name,hr_period.name
FROM hr_employee
FULL OUTER JOIN hr_movement
ON hr_employee.ad_client_id=hr_movement.ad_client_id
FULL OUTER JOIN hr_concept
ON hr_movement.ad_client_id=hr_employee.ad_client_id /*<- here*/
FULL OUTER JOIN hr_period
ON hr_concept.ad_client_id=hr_employee.ad_client_id /*<- and here*/
```

You're joining tables, but don't use these tables in the join condition. Apart from that MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOINs`. They are realized like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

**There is no `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL**. See [7.2.12. Outer Join Simplification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html) and [12.2.8.1. JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> You can emulate `FULL OUTER JOIN` using
>   UNION (from MySQL 4.0.0 on):
>
> with two tables t1, t2:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
> LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> UNION
> SELECT * FROM t1
> RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> ```
>
> with three tables t1, t2, t3:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
> LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
> UNION
> SELECT * FROM t1
> RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
> UNION
> SELECT * FROM t1
> RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
> ```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join?rq=1)

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978663/mysql-full-join?rq=1)