# How to perform FULL JOIN in Zend Framework 2 Zend\Db

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework2

I know it is possible to perform followings with ZF 2

```
$select->join(//$select is zend db sql select
                            array(
                                'cs' => 'table1'), 
                                'ts.id=cs.cs_id', 
                                array(),$select::JOIN_TYPE);
```

according to the manual (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html)JOIN_TYPE can be any of follows, and they are producing what they mean

```
JOIN_INNER 
JOIN_OUTER 
JOIN_LEFT   
JOIN_RIGHT
```

but I simply want to add normal join $select->join produce an Inner join. Dose any one know any way

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'normal join'? If you mean using `JOIN` on its own, it's the same as using `INNER JOIN` -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/565640/1112089

Comment: mysql doesn't have full join http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978663/mysql-full-join

Comment: full join emulation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i get what you mean but maybe this will help you

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;



 $select10 = new Select;
    $select10->from('foo')->join('zac', 'm = n');
    // 'SELECT "foo".*, "zac".* FROM "foo" INNER JOIN "zac" ON "m" = "n"';
```

If you follow the link below you may find what you need.

[References here](https://gist.github.com/ralphschindler/3949548)