# Database sql syntax, what is wrong with this sql code

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
SELECT customer.first_name,
       customer.last_name,
       orders.order_number
FROM customer
     FULL OUTER JOIN orders ON customer.id = orders.customerid
ORDER BY customer.last_name;
```

Comment: syntax wise - nothing. What happens when you run it?

Comment: when i run it , it show nothing but error

Comment: whats the error...

Comment: Can you please share the error you're getting?

Comment: Error

SQL query: Documentation

SELECT customer.first_name,customer.last_name,orders.order_number
from customer
full outer join orders on 
customer.id=orders.customerid
ORDER by customer.last_name LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer join orders on
customer.id=orders.customerid
ORDER by customer.last_nam' at line 3

Comment: customer.id = orders.customer.id    ??? I would need to see your table structures

Comment: i just wanted use full outer join with two table customer and order

Comment: At least MySQL doesn't have FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Are `Full Joins` supported? try it with a `Union`

Comment: thanks , yeah may be  mysql not support full outer join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978663/mysql-full-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT customer.first_name,customer.last_name,orders.order_number from customer
full outer join orders on customer.id=orders.customerid ORDER by customer.last_name;

Nothing wrong in this query just check your column name

Comment: full join isnt supported

Comment: full outer join support in sql server