# Sample SQL Join Code from Famous Sites Doesn't Validate?

Tags: sql, mysqli

Here's [sample SQL Full Outer Join code](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) from w3schools:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Testing it in online validators (https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ and https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/) throws an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name' at line 5

[w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-full-outer-join.php) has this sample SQL code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Sample code found on SO is pretty much the same code and throws the same error in the validators and on my dev system.

[image]

- Does that make any sense?
- What is the correct SQL for this?

Comment: look at: SELECT column_name(s).   You did not provide column_name but *. I think there is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those query are `MSSQL` Query not `mysql` and that two sites are mysql query validator.
You don't have FULL JOINS on MySQL, but you can sure emulate [them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978663/mysql-full-join).

sample code to emulate FULL OUTER JOIN on MYSQL :

```
    SELECT * FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM t1
    RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```