# Insert data in a table from two other tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I need to insert data in a table from two other tables that have the same schema.

I have an exception :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FULL JOIN data e2 ON e1.siren = e2.siren' at line 3

Here's My code :

```
string MergeTables = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO Table3 (a,b) 
SELECT e1.a, e2.b
FROM bilan e1 FULL JOIN data e2
ON e1.id= e2.id;

");
```

Comment: MySQL does not support `FULL JOIN`

Comment: Side note: `Format` is *redundant* here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978663/mysql-full-join

Comment: Thank you @DmitryBychenko !!

Comment: Thank you @MadhurBhaiya  !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `;` at the end of your sql and remove `FULL` due to `MySQL` do not support `FULL JOIN`

```
  string MergeTables = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO exercices (AF,region) 
  SELECT e1.AF, e2.region FROM bilan e1 
    JOIN data e2 ON e1.siren = e2.siren
   ");
```

Comment: I did that values inserted to third table correctly but i have another exception in the end of the method " Fatal error encountered during command execution. " here my code ( var conn = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(MergeTables, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); )

Comment: @mecab95 You can update your question(then cancel my answer) or open a new question with the deital information of the error

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL does not support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html) `FULL JOIN`

[Try to emulate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384312/2469308) as follows:

```
SELECT e1.AF FROM bilan e1
LEFT JOIN data e2 ON e1.siren = e2.siren
UNION
SELECT e2.region FROM data e2
RIGHT JOIN bilan e1 ON e2.siren = e1.siren
```