# Full join multiple Doctrine QueryBuilder instances

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, full-outer-join

I created two query builder instances using a helper function like this:

```
public function openOrdersQueryBuilder()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('order')
        ->where("order.state != 'done'")
        ->andWhere(...)
        ...;
}

$confirmedDateSummary = $this->openOrdersQueryBuilder()
    ->groupBy('summarydate')
    ->select('confirmed AS date, count(order) AS count_confirmed');
$orderedDateSummary = $this->openOrdersQueryBuilder()
    ->groupBy('summarydate')
    ->select('ordered AS summarydate, count(order) AS count_ordered');
```

My actual queries are a little more involved.

Now I would like to `FULL JOIN` those two but I don't know how. I basically have two questions.

1. If at all possible, how can I create a third `QueryBuilder` that can consume the two existing ones as subqueries and JOIN them on the date columns?
2. Neither Doctrine nor MySQL support `FULL JOIN`. How to emulate it? Unfortunately Doctrine also does not seem to have common table expressions.

Some raw MySQL around whatever `$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSql()` produces would also be appreciated. With the help of common table expressions I tried to use a `LEFT JOIN` `UNION`ed with a `RIGHT JOIN` as a [general workaround for MySQL missing FULL JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36001694). However I ran into the problem that `$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSql()` only produces column names like `sclr_0`, `sclr_1` etc..

If 1. is possible, I presume I could achieve the same workaround without CTEs and without raw SQL at the cost of a rather bloaty query.

The question title should have made it obvious that the problem I am having is NOT a MySQL problem per se - neither SQL nor MySQL are part of the title. Apparently this was not obvious, so let me explain: I only mentioned MySQL because it is the database I have at hand. If my question can not be answered with a database-agnostic solution which would naturally be preferred, a workaround using some raw MySQL would also be appreciated. Least preferred would be a solution that only involves raw MySQL but as I pointed out above I am very much aware how to achieve this on my own. Obviously I would like to use as many benefits of the Doctrine ORM as I can instead. How to achieve this is the question.

Comment: Please read my question carefully; also please read the answer that I linked to show what I already know. Finally please read the question that has been linked as the duplicate. You will find that the latter two are the same. My question is obviously more nuanced than the answer I linked myself so it can not be a duplicate of the question that was linked as a duplicate. So please vote to reopen my question. Afterwards we should delete this comment, maybe even revert my explanatory edit of the question, because it does not really add much. @ the closer, please take a little more care next time.